# How i get views.py variable to js file?

Tags: javascript, python, django

views.py

```
def somefunction(request):
    var = True 


    return render(request, dasboard.html)
```

```
myfirst.js

function myFunction() {
}
```

How I get var from views.py into the myfirst.js function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to give a 100% correct answer without knowing the templating engine you are using (DTL, Jinja2?). However, if `var` doesn't contain any sensitive/private data, the general solution is to pass `var` to your html template through [the `context` parameter of the `render` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```py
# views.py

views.py
def somefunction(request):
    var = True 
    context = { "var": var }
    return render(request, dasboard.html, context)
```

Then, expose `var` as a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on a html element in your template (the exact implementation will change based on the templating engine you are using):

```html
<!-- dashboard.html -->

<div id="info" data-var="{{ var }}" >
    ...
</div>
```

Finally, in your javascript file, you simply retrieve the same html element and access `var` through the special [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
// myfirst.js

function myFunction() {
    var infoElement = document.getElementById("info");
    var varValue = infoElement.dataset.var;
}
```